# Move Child Rigidbody with Mouse Smoothly Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my scene, I have a moving platform that have a child object, the child is a rigidbody that (should) move with mouse position. I have two issues in the code below: first, the object didn't move when it's a child, it only move when it has no parent, second, the movement is not smooth enough. How can I solve that?

Script:

```
Rigidbody RB;
float Speed = 10.0f;

Vector3 InitialMouse;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    float Xmovement = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float Zmovement = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3(Xmovement * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0, Zmovement * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        RB.MovePosition(transform.position + Movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Sociallab, so I am really not an expert with rigidbodies. But as you say it moves when it has no parent but not as a child, in your line "RB.MovePosition(transform.position + Movement)", where is your rigidbody located? Also explore the difference between transform.position or the transform.localposition.

Comment: @gkapellmann The rigidbody stay in his start position, it stuck to the parent and didn't move, and I've also tried transform.localposition but it still didn't move!

Comment: OK, two things that come to my mind too. 1.- Have you tried making the RB kinematic? And/or try multiplying the movement for a direction, say  "RB.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.right * Movement)"